# Bootstrap Panels not working in angular latest cli

Tags: angular

i'm new to angular i have installed latest angular cli. bootstrap button and other things are working but bootstrap panel is not working
it shows only the text.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
  <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
</div>
```

this is angular.json file

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css", "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

anybody knows the issue .

Thanks.

Comment: which version of angular-cli you are using?

Comment: you should provide all relevant code such as your config and style. I'm pretty sure you didn't check https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap

Comment: i have installed the bootstrap correctly .i have updated thread

Comment: latest angular cli.  version 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 panels classes different from Bootstrap 3.
If you install bootstrap in angular, by default bootstrap 4 will come.
Install this one
npm install boostrap@3.0.0 --save

Comment: that command gave an error  "  npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for boostrap@3.0.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist."

Comment: npm install bootstrap@3.3.6 --save    use this command or call this cdn in index.html file
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: Thank you very much  @ vinaykumar0459.  you fixed the issue. so can't we use panels in bootstrap 4. is there a different way to use it.

Comment: use bootstrap 3 for panels, if you want to use bootstrap 4 only then go through these links
1.  https://codepen.io/gcharles/pen/gMaEMb
2.  https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/bootstrap-4-cards-replacing-panels/10456

Comment: @ vinaykumar0459 Thanks